# Определить, попадает ли точка с координатами {x,y} в закрашенные области

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Задача состоит в том, чтобы определить, попадает ли точка с координатами {x,y} в закрашенные области.

Из входных данных мы имеем радиус окружности и сторону квадрата.

[image: рисунок]

Comment: Код за Вас написать что ли? Здесь на это смотрят неодобрительно.

Comment: У меня есть пробелы в математике и не знаю чем здесь лучше воспользоваться, код я могу написать сам, если будут наводки какие-то.
Намного проще было бы, если тут был квадрат, а не ромб

Comment: @Roman, а про уравнение прямой, слышал?)  Ромб, 4 разных прямых.

Comment: Вроде дикий дубликат, токо был тут недели 3 назад такой вопрос (в 1 и второй квадрат, 3 и 4 полукруг)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точки внутри (или на) окружности удовлетворяют неравенству:

```
x * x + y * y <= R * R
```

`R` - радиус окружности.

Точка находится ниже (или на) прямой, если

```
y <= k * x + b
```

`>=` - выше (или на).

Уравнение прямой в первом квадранте

```
y = -x + A / sqrt(2)
```

`A` - сторона квадрата.

Answer (score 1):

Начните с написания программы, которая проверяет, что точка попадает в круг радиуса R.

Для этого надо проверить, что расстояние от центра круга до точки меньше радиуса.

Формула расстояния есть в учебнике/википедии.

Теперь надо научиться проверять попадание в повернутый квадрат. Сразу весь квадрат проверять сложно, попробуйте проверять попадание в треугольник из осей координат и прямой линии под 45 градусов.

Потом останется только совместить.

Answer (score 1):

А точки внутри квадрата -

```
|x|+|y| < a
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int32_t main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        double r, a, x, y;
        cin >> r >> a >> x >> y;
        // r - радиус круга, a - сторона квадрата, 
        // x, y - точка
        // попадаем в закрашенную область, когда 
        // попали в круг, но не попали в квадрат
        if (x * 2 + y * 2 <= r * r &&
            abs(x) + abs(y) > a)
            cout << "Yes\n";
        else
            cout << "No\n";
    }
}
```